# Firefox Sync between two OS on the same computer

Tags: windows, linux, firefox, firefox-sync

I have a computer which runs two OS (Win7 and Ubuntu).
Both OS have Firefox installed and sync is set up under Windows. I do not have any other computers with firefox.
Is it possible to sync this two using Firefox Sync?

As far, as I understood, both Firefoxes need to run simultaneously for syncing set up.
Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. You have to go to the sync options of the first OS and get your recovery-key. Once you got that key, you can click "pair device" on your second OS and then click "I don't have the device with me". There you can log-in using your credentials and your recovery key and both of your Firefoxes will synchronize.

Answer (score 0):

When you setup Firefox's Sync in each OS, just specify a different Computer Name.

Comment: Second firefox asks me if I an account - I click yes - it offers to pair a device. Where should I choose a different computer name?

Comment: It should be the last thing on the Sync tab of the Tools | Options dialog.

Comment: Hmm... It seems that you misunderstood the problem. I have one firefox with sync already set up (it has computer name like "georg's Firefox on Windows NT 6.1; WOW64"). And I need to add another browser (from Ubuntu, with name like "Firefox on Ubuntu") to my swarm. Computer names are already different.

Comment: Perhaps I do. If the two OS's have a independent Firefox installations then you should be able to simple specify that each is a different computer/device. Also, both Firefoxes do not need to be running at the same same, your shared sync info is stored on a remote Mozilla server somewhere.